# Create a separator with a text in the menubar

Tags: qt, menubar

What I want is shown in the docs in the picture http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qactiongroup.html#details, but I cannot figure out how to do it. I can create a separator by

```
QAction * separator = new QAction("This is ignored", actionGroup);
separator->setSeparator(true);
```

but then it is just a line. How is the "Alignment" text added to the action in the example?

Comment: http://www.qtforum.org/article/32038/labeled-menu-separators.html

Answer (score 1):

Following your link, then to the "Menus" example link (where your example is excerpted from) and then to mainwindow.cpp (which is one of the source files for that example), I reach: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-mainwindows-menus-mainwindow-cpp.html

The last function in that source file is createMenus which contains the following:

```
formatMenu = editMenu->addMenu(tr("&Format"));
formatMenu->addAction(boldAct);
formatMenu->addAction(italicAct);
formatMenu->addSeparator()->setText(tr("Alignment"));
formatMenu->addAction(leftAlignAct);
formatMenu->addAction(rightAlignAct);
formatMenu->addAction(justifyAct);
formatMenu->addAction(centerAct);
formatMenu->addSeparator();
formatMenu->addAction(setLineSpacingAct);
formatMenu->addAction(setParagraphSpacingAct);
```

The important bit is the fourth line in: setText on the separator added by addSeparator()

Comment: Well. Trying to follow documentation example in Qt 5.6 using
     addSepatarator()->setText("Whatever");
does not work. Separator still has no text.

Comment: Maybe it is style-dependent

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a `QLabel` with a `QWidgetAction` (e.g. in python):

```
label = QtGui.QLabel("<b>At least it is rich text!</b>")

label_action = QtGui.QWidgetAction(self)
label_action.setDefaultWidget(label)

menu.addAction(label_action)
```